# Is $|f'(x)| \le 2\sqrt{\alpha \beta}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function and $\alpha, \beta > 0$. Assume that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$|f(x)| \le \alpha$ and $|f
''(x)| \le \beta$. Prove that
$|f'(x)| \le 2\sqrt{\alpha \beta}$.

I've tried using Taylor's theorem and the mean value theorem, but not luck. Any hints to point me in the right direction?